# How to convert a csv dataset to a numpy array readable by opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, opencv, image-processing

I have a csv dataset namely sign language mnist dataset. It contains information of 28x28 images with its pixel information. I would like to convert this dataset into a numpy array that can be read by opencv3. A numpy array where i can manipulate through opencv. I would like to apply histogram of oriented gradients into this dataset through opencv.

I have already successfully converted it into a numpy array and was able to isolate a row and reshape it into a 28x28 array. The row has a label at the beginning and i have also split it with only the 28x28 pixel data. I have used matplotlib to successfully plot it however I can't seem to use cv2.imshow() on the numpy array. I also know that opencv can only read certain datatypes and i have tried converting my data numpy array into both int32 and float but it still didnt work.

Here is how the CSV file looks like:
[The CSV file showing the first 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJDWk.jpg)

Here is the file:
[Sign Language CSV dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LczrakCWFxzIpSc6AcbLSIDloUdVfNxl/view?usp=sharing)

[Site Where I got the Dataset[Kaggle.com - Sign Language Mnist]](https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist)

The 1st column is the label for the image and the rest are the pixels. It goes up to the pixel 784 column.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

data = np.genfromtxt('sign_mnist_test.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

labels = data[1:, 0].astype(np.float)
value1 = data[0, 1:].astype(np.float) #the 1st row of the dataset

reshaped = np.reshape(value1, (28, 28))

cv2.imshow('image', reshaped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is how my numpy array for the 1st row looks like:

[Numpy array of the 1st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSaSv.jpg)

Here is the output:

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp0SQ.jpg)

I expect it to show a 28x28 training image(a hand image) however it only shows a plain white 28x28 image with no features.

```
plt.imshow(reshaped, cmap="Greys")
plt.show()
```

[Output using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTxhR.jpg)

I am using PyCharm as IDE.

I am also looking for alternative options so that i can use my dataset for openCV if there is any solution that is better.

Comment: Please provide enough data so we can run your code... enough lines of the CSV.

Comment: I have added images that can hopefully provide enough data.

Comment: We can't read numbers from an image!!!

Comment: The csv gives information on the color value of each pixel. I tried reading an image using cv2.imread() and printed it in console and it outputs a numpy array with color values. I will post a picture in which I was able to plot it using matplotlib and it outputs an image.

Comment: I mean you have provided a **picture** of a CSV file, We can't read that, we need a text file not an image file please. Thanks.

Comment: ahh sorry about that. ill post the file

Comment: I have posted the file and the site i downloaded it from. Sorry for not understanding that I need to post the file. Thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have made it a float on this line:

```
value1 = data[0, 1:].astype(np.float)
```

You need to preferably pass an `np.uint8` to `cv2.imshow()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used resize instead of reshape

```
data = pd.read_csv("sign_mnist_train/sign_mnist_train.csv") # images of 28x28 
labels = data.label
data = data.drop(columns=["label"])
value1 = data.iloc[0].astype(np.uint8) 
reshaped = np.resize(value1, (28, 28))
cv2.imshow('image', reshaped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```